# Ph.D. in a ghost town. Worth it or not?

Tags: phd, quitting

I have been living in this town for 16 months, but I am in this Ph.D. position only for 4 months. For the other 12 months, I had been working as an employee in the same research group.

I really like the research, the project, the prof., the colleagues and also the stipend. The only thing I hate about this place is the town where I am living. It is becoming more and more difficult to stay sane. It is only a few thousand "old" people and things close at 6:30 in the evening. I have been used to the life of a city (in and out of my home country). This small town is driving me crazy. I am trying to be strong, but I am not sure if I can keep it up for 4 years.

Comment: How far remote is the next big town? Maybe you could build a social life there.

Comment: About one and a half hours by train. Each train journey costs like 30 EUR.

Comment: I know people in a similar situation who prefer to live in the next larger city, the commute may take up some time but it may be worth it. Often you can get cheaper tickets if you're commuting to your workplace.

Comment: About the money, take into account that you probably have significant savings for rent. I recently lived in the middle of a major European city and paid 1250 Euros for a one-room apartment.

Comment: Also, the public transport system might provide significant discounts for regular users. In Germany, the BahnCard 50 reduces the fee of each train ticket by 50%, for 230 Euro per year.

Comment: In many (northern) European countries, 18:30 closures are quite normal.  Where I did my PhD, shops mostly closed at 17:00 or before on weekdays, 14:00 on weekends (one interesting shop I never managed to visit even once, as they were open only Mo-Fr 12–16 and 10 km from my workplace).  Rent was dirt cheap (some rooms were less than 150 €/month).  World city nightlife may imply rents out of reach for a PhD student in many countries.

Comment: It is rare to find a PhD position that you enjoy the research, colleagues, supervisor and you are being paid enough! The trick is to find leisure activities that don't rely on shops being open. You could move to a larger town (wherever students live), join some university student groups, take up a musical instrument, join a choir... If you do something one or two evenings a week that involves interaction, then you may feel more positive about the town. What do your colleagues do for fun?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I exactly want that. I want to live in a larger German city, maybe in a student dorm with single separate room and a shared kitchen. Not a small Swiss town with cheaper rent and non-existent diversity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't commit to anything until you know your options. If you can find a more "suitable" position then you can decide at that time.

But evaluate all the aspects, including the support you get, and the support you might get. Not just financial support.

One advantage of your current situation is that you aren't going to spend more time on the degree than needed and you aren't going to be distracted by nightlife and such.